# data save on txt file using golang

Tags: go

I am trying to save my data to txt file , which is working fine , but when I give it to new data it is stored in the place of old data but I want it to that new data will store next to my old data...! please help

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log"
    "os"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    stop := Stoploss()
    
    fmt.Println(stop)
}

func Stoploss() string {
    stoploss := 12342
    str := strconv.Itoa(stoploss)
    Time := time.Now()
    value := `stoploss =` + str + `\n at the time of -> ` + Time.Format("01-02-2006 15:04:05")

    data, err := os.Create("stoploss.txt")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("whoops", err)
    }
    io.Copy(data, strings.NewReader(value))
    return str
}
```

Comment: Use os.OpenFile. The docs even have an example of this https://golang.org/pkg/os/#example_OpenFile_append

Comment: you might want to use this standard go package https://golang.org/pkg/log/

Comment: If you read the documentation on os.Create (https://pkg.go.dev/os#Create), it says "If the file already exists, it is truncated."

Comment: thanku @Pablo Flores

Answer (score 0):

`os.Create("stoploss.txt")` truncates file if already exists. So you need to use `os.OpenFile` function to append new content to already exists file.